# Optimization algorithm, how to develop this problem

Tags: algorithms, math, optimization

I have a situation where I would like your input and think over / solve algorithm.

The specs

> There are inventories with a specified amount of capacity. 
>  'X
>   (width) and Y (time)' creates together a total space. '60 * 100 =
>   6000'. In reality "width" are a business value unit, but we can talk width here.
>
> Now there also are boxes, which take a part of the space. 
>  Each
>   box take width (X) and time (Y). Two boxes with 80 * 20 each, will
>   fill a inventory with 1600+1600. It will result a fill factor, 2800
>   space left in the inventory, after the boxes are added. Each box
>   always belong to it's inventory.
>
> There exist unlimited, serial dependent, inventories with boxes added individually. 
>   The former inventory have to be performed before next are performed.
>
> Boxes themself have a attribute, like a color, which make a ownership
>   in higher context. Like a "give me all boxes of color -yellow-"
>   context. I.e. to find out which inventories contain that color. A box
>   with same color can exist several times, even in same inventory. But
>   if in same inventory, they have unique box-id's.

The problem

> There have to be added optimization strategy which make width (X) adjustable. Time (Y) is still fixed and can't change. The optimization
>   rule is that available space in former inventory should be filled with
>   a part/slice from second inventory.
>
> Time must fit. I.e. 2x15 or 1x25 can fit to 1x30. 1x35 can't fit. Also the width added to former, must  be reduced from second.
>   Remember that a box  isn't allowed to be removed from it's inventory (but width can be
>   1 as minimum). Though, on adjustment, new boxes have to be created in the former
>   inventory.

It's a mathematical theory but i mainly want to transform a algorithm of this kind, into code. Or give the question a glance of what kind of theories to look for. Perhaps this is a common problem? or too complex considered as "re-invent the wheel" and recommend to buy a third party module.

[Edit] 'length' changed to 'width'
Added a graphic to better illustrate how the optimization rule will apply.
[image]

There are a little green piece remaind at right, after optimization, because of the "at least 1 width must remain"-rule. The red and blue did not fit fully.

Comment: I am confused by you "Y-time", do you mean width?

Comment: I think his use of time for Y means that it's how long the space is occupied by the item.

Comment: Now graphics are added, to clarify the problem,

Comment: Should i be more clear in my attempt to describe, or is the alorithm hard to get?

Comment: I think there can be a hint related to two dimensional stock cutting problem. There also is a kind of problem called knapsack, which is more  about weight. However this is also about move load between areas.